# Get value form form drop down list using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below browser rendered code from which I have to get selected value form drop down so please suggest me,

```
<select onchange="return (DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));" onfocus="return (DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));"
onblur="return (DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" id="ctl00_m_g_9b533b93_8578_445e_8f07_9d3d3923440c_FormControl0_V1_I1_D27"
scriptclass="DropDownList" class="q_fnajakhee6csPfK0_1 m_fnajakhee6csPfK0_1 b4_fnajakhee6csPfK0_1 br_fnajakhee6csPfK0_1"
wrapped="true" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="40" formid="ctl00_m_g_9b533b93_8578_445e_8f07_9d3d3923440c_FormControl0"
originalid="V1_I1_D27" tabindex="0" title="" style="direction: ltr">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Pending" selected="">Pending</option>
<option value="Approve">Approve</option>
<option value="Reject">Reject</option>
<option value="Change Topic">Change Topic</option>
```

Thanks,
Digambar K.

Comment: Have you try anything ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val(); // where 'this' is the dropdown
```